# Mostrar datos de tabla dinámica en popup/modal en Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap, laravel-5

Tengo un sistema el cual realiza una búsqueda a una base de datos para traer información de un usuario(hace una consulta a una tabla de usuarios). Esta información se ordena y coloca en una tabla de manera correcta.

Lo que necesito es que al momento de dar clic a un registro de la tabla este me muestre un PopUp o Modal en donde se muestre una información diferente a la mostrada en la tabla pero que tiene que ver con el mismo usuario.

Ejemplo:
Si el usuario selecciona a Juan Pérez, el sistema realice una consulta a la tabla de compras y muestre todas las compras de juan en el mes.

Aquí se muestra mi codigo de HTML donde se muestran los campos al cual el usuario puede dar clic:

```
   @foreach($resultado as $res)
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{ $res->Codigo }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $res->Nombre }}</td>    
                      <td>{{ $res->Zona }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $res->Plazo }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $res->CredAut  }}</td>
                      <td>
  <a title="Mostrar Gastos por mes" class="pull-left" href="#PlaceModal2-{{$res->Codigo}}" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="false" title="{{ number_format($res->ConsumoPromXfac,2) }}">{{ number_format($res->ConsumoPromXfac,2) }} </a>
                      <td>{{ $res->DiasPromPago }}</td>
                      <td>
  <a title="Mostrar Consumo de años anteriores" class="pull-left" href="#PlaceModal1-{{$res->Codigo}}" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="false" title="{{ number_format($res->Consumoant,2) }}">{{ number_format($res->Consumoant,2) }} </a>
                      <td>{{ $res->SaldoActual }}</td>
                      <td>
  <a title="Mostrar Detalle de vencido" class="pull-left" href="#PlaceModal-{{$res->Codigo}}" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="false" title="{{ number_format($res->SaldoVencido,2) }}">{{ number_format($res->SaldoVencido,2) }} </a>
                      </td>
                 </tr>
    @endforeach
```